# How Bell turn backed electricity fluctuations to sound?

Tags: communication

Even though I could get how [Alexander Graham Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Graham_Bell) turned sound vibrations into electrical fluctuation as said in this article on [Telephone history](https://web.archive.org/web/20131207083756/http://www.privateline.com/mt_telephonehistory/) I couldn't get how he turned back electricity fluctuations to sound?

I can't get how a small current can make a [diaphragm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_%28acoustics%29) to vibrate to produce sound waves?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a history question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The component is called a [speaker or a loudspeaker](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker) and Alexander Graham Bell was indeed the person who invented this component in 1876. A current goes to a coil which acts like a magnet and depending on the magnitude of the current, it attracts or repels a static magnet that is attached to a piece of paper.

[image]

In this way, the oscillations of the electric current are converted to mechanical oscillations of the piece of the paper on the loudspaker (next to the magnet), and oscillations of the paper create oscillations of the air – the sound.

Comment: :Sorry but I couldn't see any _static_ magnet in [Bell's liquid transmitter](http://www.howitworksdaily.com/how-bells-telephone-worked/).Could you help me.

Comment: Justin, you are confused. The liquid transmitter is the *microphone*, the thing that listens, not the *speaker*, the thing that speaks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_transmitter So of course the liquid transmitter has no static magnet, it's on the other side, the speaker that has the magnet.

Comment: :Okay I'll check that and come back.

Comment: To be sure, the microphone works by measuring the changing resistance - and the resistance is changing because a membrane in the liquid vibrates which changes the amount of liquid between the two endpoints of a wire, and therefore the resistance.